# SYMFONY DESERIALIZER ERROR: The type of the attribute for class must be one of "Object[]" but ("array" given)

Tags: php, json, symfony, serialization, deserialization

I have a Tags model (not an entity) with a child Tag model array property.

```php
class Tags
{
    private array $tags;

    public function addTag(Tag $tag): bool{}

    public function removeTag(Tag $tag): bool{}

    public function setTags(array $tags): self{}

    public function getTags(): array{}
```

And it was correctly serialized.

```json
{
    "tags": [
        {
            "slug": "a_tag",
            "name": "A Tag",
            "description": "This is a nice tag!"
        }
    ]
}
```

To deserialize I do:

```php
use Symfony\Component\PropertyInfo\Extractor\ReflectionExtractor;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncode;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;


        $json = file_get_contents($this->fileName);
        $encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];
        $normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, new ReflectionExtractor())];
        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

        return $serializer->deserialize($json, Tags::class, 'json');
```

But when I try to deserialize, I get an error:

> The type of the "tags" attribute for class "App\Model\Tags" must be
> one of "App\Model\Tag[]" ("array" given).

This doesn't even make sense. It's not possible to type an array in PHP, so why it's giving this error?

I think this is somewhat related to [Recursive Denormalization and Type Safety](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#recursive-denormalization-and-type-safety), but I don't get how to fix it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use use an ArrayDenormalizer.

```php
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ArrayDenormalizer;

        $json = file_get_contents($this->fileName);

        $encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];
        $normalizers = [
            new ArrayDenormalizer(),
            new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, new ReflectionExtractor())
        ];
        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

        return $serializer->deserialize($json, Tags::class, 'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration in Symfony yaml config.

```
services:
  property_normalizer:
    class: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\PropertyNormalizer
    tags: [ serializer.normalizer ]
    arguments:
      $propertyTypeExtractor: '@Symfony\Component\PropertyInfo\PropertyDescriptionExtractorInterface'
  object_normalizer:
    class: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer
    tags: [ serializer.normalizer ]
  get_set_method_normalizer:
    class: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer
    tags: [ serializer.normalizer ]
  array_denormalizer:
    class: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ArrayDenormalizer
    tags: [ serializer.denormalizer ]
```

It works good with collections.

```
    /**
     * @var Tag[] Tags
     */
    #[OA\Property(type: 'array', items: new OA\Items(ref: '#/components/schemas/Tag'))]
    #[Assert\Valid(traverse: true)]
    protected array $tags;
```